# using delegate to update wpf label info from other class

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have Wpf window and corresponding `ViewModel`. There is a label on `MainWindow` which is bound to property `CurrentActionTaken`

```
private string _CurrentActionTaken;
public string CurrentActionTaken
{
   get{
         return _CurrentActionTaken;
   }
   set{
        _CurrentActionTaken = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("CurrentActionTaken");
   }
}
```

I have a `BackgroundWorker` which calls private method `WorkerDoWork` inside same viewmodel

```
_Worker = new BackgroundWorker();
...
_Worker.DoWork += (obj, e) => WorkerDoWork(_selectedEnumAction, _SelectedCountry);
_Worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Inside `WorkerDoWork` I want to call other class which will take the hard work, and I want to display currently processing item on my `MainWindow` label (bound to `CurrentActionTaken` property)

```
private void WorkerDoWork(Enums.ProviderAction action, CountryCombo selCountry) 
{
    _CurrentActionTaken = "entered WorkerDoWork method";
    OnPropertyChanged("CurrentActionTaken");
    new MyOtherClass(_selectedEnumAction, _SelectedCountry);
    ...
}
```

here I was thinking to use method which will be called on `OtherClass` data iteration method:

```
public static void DataProcessUpdateHandler(string item)
{
   MessageBox.Show(item);
}
```

and finally call from iteration somewhere in `OtherClass`:

```
foreach (var item in items)
{                    
    ...
    MainViewModel.DataProcessUpdateHandler(item.NameOfProcessedItem);
}
```

Everything works with displaying item inside `MessageBox` in `DataProcessUpdateHandler`

```
MessageBox.Show(item);
```

My question is how can change this and use

```
_CurrentActionTaken = item;
OnPropertyChanged("CurrentActionTaken");
```

Right now it's not possible cause `DataProcessUpdateHandler` is static method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick and dirty way:

```
(Application.Current.MainWindow.DataContext as MainViewModel).CurrentActionTaken = "Executing evil plan to take control of the world."
```

Of course you should adapt if your `MainViewModel` is reachable through a property inside the MainWindow:

```
Application.Current.MainWindow.Model.CurrentActionTaken = "Executing evil plan to take control of the world."
```

The "correct" way would be to pass around your view model (or any other intermediate object) but if you want to keep things simple and can use the above method then IMHO useless to make more complex stuff.

EDIT: at your demand to be cleaner you could pass around the VM:

```
private void WorkerDoWork(Enums.ProviderAction action, CountryCombo selCountry) 
{
    _CurrentActionTaken = "entered WorkerDoWork method";
    OnPropertyChanged("CurrentActionTaken");
    new MyOtherClass(_selectedEnumAction, this);
    ...
}
```

And the `MyOtherClass` instance would have access to the whole VM: `_SelectedCountry` and `CurrentActionTaken`.

You can go further by defining an `ISupportCurrentActionTaken` interface to decouple your `MyOtherClass` from `MainViewModel` but if they live in the same project this is clearly overkill.

Comment: thanks, can you recommend me any better solution to this (having my question in mind) which can be more complex in general but easier to maintain.